# Converting TIMESTAMP to Char in Oracle Ibatis

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ibatis

I am trying to run a query in Oracle ibatis to fetch content of a table. One of the column 'CREATED_ON' is of TIMESTAMP datatype. When I try to convert this to String using TO_CHAR function I get the below exception.

The goal is to get a Map of column headers & values from this query. If I remove the TO_CHAR from the query, I get the result in the Map without any exceptions but the CREATED_ON column values are oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@3524fead.

**`EXCEPTION`**

```
com.ctg.dms.exceptions.DMSApplicationException: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in com/ctg/dms/dao/ibatis/oracle/AuditLogAccessControlSQLs.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a result map.  
--- Check the auditLogAccessControl.findAccessLogEntriesForFileExport-AutoResultMap.  
--- Check the result mapping for the 'TO_CHAR(A.CREATED_ON)' property.  
--- Cause: com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no WRITEABLE property named 'CREATED_ON)' in class 'java.lang.Object'at com.ctg.dms.dao.impl.sql.ibatis.AuditLogAccessControlDAOImpl.findAccessLogEntriesForFileExport(AuditLogAccessControlDAOImpl.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.findAccessLogEntriesForFileExport(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

**`Ibatis XML Mapping`**

```
<statement id="findAccessLogEntriesForFileExport" resultClass="HashMap">
   SELECT (SELECT VALUE FROM REF_DATA WHERE ID_REF_DATA = A.ID_EVENT_TYPE) EVENT_TYPE, 
      A.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION, U.USERNAME AS CREATED_BY, TO_CHAR(A.CREATED_ON, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
   FROM AUDIT_LOG_ACCESS_CONTROL A
   JOIN USER_DETAILS U  ON A.CREATED_BY = U.ID_USER_DETAILS
   ORDER BY A.CREATED_ON DESC
</statement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Abatis, but it seems that it requires to map this field to a field in your java object. You should give this an function an alias (=> TO_CHAR(A.CREATED_ON, 'DD-MM-YYYY') CREATED_ON), and make sure that the type (VARCHAR2/STRING) match in your java defintion.